# When loading a JSON from mongo into a Python Dataframe, how should you handle NaN?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting an error when I try and "flatten" json into a dataframe, I believe it is because some of the cells have NaN in. What is the best way to handle this?

The Error I get is "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'"

```
import pandas as pd

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')


#Import Counterparties
counterpartydb = client.counterparties
cptylist = counterpartydb.counterparties

cptylists = pd.DataFrame(list(cptylist.find()))
details = pd.DataFrame(list(cptylists['details']))

CurRating = pd.DataFrame(list(cptylists['currentRating']))
```

[image: Example of cptylists for example]

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB is schemaless, sometimes there will be Null values in a response. You can iterate over these and check to see if the value is None.

```
cptylists = pd.DataFrame(list(cptylist.find()))
creditRating = []
for rating in cptylists['creditRating']:
    if rating['creditRating'] is not None:
        creditRating.append(rating['creditRating'])
    else:
        creditRating.append('No value in database')
creditRating = pd.DataFrame(creditRating)
```

The list comprehension version of this would be something like:

```
if 'creditRating' in cptylists:
    creditRating = pd.DataFrame([k for k in (cptylists['creditRating'] or [])] )
```

Comment: thanks a lot drinck, I'm getting a Type error now and haven't been able to solve it, do you have any thoughts?

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: My guess is that particular key doesn't exist in your MongoDB query results. To find if a particular key was returned you can use `if 'creditRating' in cptylists:`